How to access all folder in email in selenium python
I used imaplib library but it is sometimes not able to access some accounts, I use poplib but it only supports accessing main mailbox but not other folders like spam
I want to use imaplib without the error of sometimes not being able to access even though I have an account I can still access it, or is there another library that supports that quickly?
